# Adding a Label to Chart js Pie Graph

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, chart.js

I'm working on adding a pie chart with Chart.js. I'm able to display the chart but would like to display a label, percentage and legend.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here's how I'm generating the pie graph:

```
dashboardRegion: (survey) ->
      male = 0
      female = 0
      survey.get('responses').each (response) ->
        if response.get('completed')
          if response.get('gender') == "male"
            male += 1
          else
            female += 1 

      genderData = [
        {
            value: male,
            color:"#9A3334",
            highlight: "#9A3334",
            label: "Male",
            labelFontFamily : "Arial",
            labelFontStyle : "normal",
            labelFontSize : 24,
            labelFontColor : "#666"
        },
        {
            value: female,
            color: "#217C7E",
            highlight: "#217C7E",
            label: "Female",
            labelFontFamily : "Arial",
            labelFontStyle : "normal",
            labelFontSize : 24,
            labelFontColor : "#666"
        }

      ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this seems to do the trick for displaying the label - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Regaddi/Chart.js/bd5bff2cd4d782fa72a529f81a8e188fc2348d77/Chart.js